# Is there a "hook_user_login_failed" hook? Or something similar?

Tags: hooks, users

I'm needing to detect when a login failure happens in Drupal and am finding it to be exceedingly difficult even after searching Google.  I have to believe this exists somewhere.

I found this post back from 2007 which seems like an entirely reasonable request for a "failed login" hook: https://www.drupal.org/node/160469 Is there something that allows this?

Thanks in advance.

AG3

Answer (score 1):

At least in Drupal 7, there is no hook for that.  The login form uses validators, one which authenticates, and another that follows and sets a form error if login failed.

One option would be to add a custom validator to the form using [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7), and check the status of login there.  See [user_login_final_validate in user.module](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_login_final_validate/7) for an example of how status is checked.